# Plot NETCDF data only for the area of interest in python?

Tags: python, mask, shapefile, netcdf

below is my code to plot data from a netcdf file.
However, I can plot the data with the basemap for the whole world.
I insert the xxxxxx shapefile through the basemap module and my goal is to plot to a specific area

```
### Import libraries###

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np


### opening NETCDF dataset MERRA###

file = 'C:.../Python_Notebook/NETCDF/MERRA2_400.statD_2d_slv_Nx.20190101.nc4'
fh = Dataset(file, mode = 'r')


### Get variables ###
# Read in 'T2M' 2-meter air temperature variable.
lons = fh.variables['lon'][:] # get longitude variables
lats = fh.variables['lat'][:] # get latitude variables
tmean = fh.variables['T2MMEAN'][:,:,:] - 273.15 # get tmean variable with conversion K for °C 

### meshgrid ###

m=Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=-20,urcrnrlat=-5,llcrnrlon=-63,urcrnrlon=-48)
lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lons, lats) # create a matrix of coordinates
xi, yi = m(lon, lat)

# Plot Data

fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
cs = m.contourf(xi,yi,np.squeeze(tmean),  cmap='rainbow') 

### Draw ### 
m.readshapefile(MTshp, name="Mt") # draw shapefile State of Mato Grosso Brazil
#m.drawcoastlines()
#m.drawcountries()
#m.drawstates()

### Draw Coordinates ###

m.drawparallels(np.arange(-80, 80, 5), labels=[1,0,0,0]) # draw parallels
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180, 180, 5), labels=[0,0,0,1]) # draw meridians

# Add Colorbar
cbar = m.colorbar(cs, location='right', pad="15%")
cbar.set_label('°C') # tmean units

### Labels ###
plt.xlabel('Longitude', fontweight='bold', labelpad=15)
plt.ylabel('Latitude', fontweight='bold', labelpad=25)

### Add Title ###
plt.title('01-01-2019 Mean Temperature', fontweight='bold', fontsize=12)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

what should i do to plot the netcdf data only in my shapefile?
what procedure should i do?
can you help me? please?
I thank you for your understanding

Comment: Hi Santos, welcome to StackOverflow. Please reformat the links. Both the hyperlinks point to the same figure. Is it what you intend to? Also, the last two lines of your code has Stackoverflow style hyperlink. Could you format that as well?

Comment: hello, due to my initial reputation, unfortunately it is not possible to insert figures in my questions, thanks for suggestions.

Comment: I've had success using https://regionmask.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html. In particular using the notebook tutorials for xarray and create your own region using shapely Polygon.

Comment: Realized I have a notebook demonstrating this.  https://gist.github.com/ebridger/a93692416ec776b0b7cb5c7b654a0e69